# Xcode El Capitan Extensions not Compatible with Yosemite

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-yosemite, osx-elcapitan, today-extension

So i have built a finished app using xcode 7.1 and el capitan, it works fine when running on el capitan but the today extension doesnt work on yosemite. If i take the exact same project and build it on xcode using yosemiti then it works fine on both operating systems.

My Questions.

1. Why doesnt building it on yosemtie make it forwards compatible El Capitan and not the other way around
2. Why does building it on El Capitan break the today view on yosemiti.

This is really starting to annoy me know because i know its a xcode problem and not a coding bug.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: i dont get any errors, on yosemite the exension just shows up without any content

Comment: Did you look at *Console.app*?

Comment: um no, could you give us the quick rundown on how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Type Cmd-Space and type "Console" and hit enter.  Have a snoop about for error messages related to your code.  If you are failing to log any potential errors in your code then you need to start doing so.  You cannot solve problems without details.  Logging is for life.

Comment: spotlight => console then look for message coming from your extension or containing words like `error`

Comment: oh yes there are two that come up.
error in CoreDragRemoveTrackingHandler      and
error in CoreDragRemoveRecieveHandler

Comment: i get this error on yosemite killed *app extension* because its use of the com.devaloper.team-identifier entitlement is not allowed